# JavaScript no me reconoce el elemento y no me da acceso a la propiedad .style

Tags: javascript, html5

No se que falla. En el script no me detecta el elemento y no puedo acceder a la propiedad.style .Lo he hecho en otras ocasiones y no me pasa esto. Algo hago mal aquí y no se que es.

```css
.volador {
  background-color:blue;
  width: 450px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 45%;
 right:-200px;
  height: 640px;
  margin-top: -320px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
  <div class="volador">
    <div class="mh">
      <div class="mv">
        <img src="imagenes/Habilidades.png">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
let divmv=document.getElementsByClassName("mv");

function cambiarColor(){

    divmv.style.backgroundColor="red";

 }

   window.addEventListener('load',cambiarColor);
```

No me da acceso a la propiedad .style. No me detecta el Elemento

Comment: La función `getElementsByClassName()` devuelve una colección de objetos debido a que en el DOM pueden existir múltiples elementos con la misma clase. Al tener tú solamente uno tendrías que acceder a la primera posición de la colección para obtener el elemento que estás buscando: `let divmv = document.getElementsByClassName("mv")[0];`

Comment: Correcto gracias.